# Tokenomics modeling

Tags: tokens

I am trying to obtain reliable information about transactions done with ICO tokens after they have been bought  (spent, burnt, sold)  in order to test with them the different cryptoasset valuation models such as the ones by Burniske (https://medium.com/@cburniske). A database with all the transactions performed will be ideal. If you think you will be able to help me with this I will be more than grateful.

Comment: I am actually working on creating an SQL database for token transfers. I have concluded the development and entering testing phase.  ERC20 only, for now.  If interested leave your contact data I will show you my work.

Comment: Sure it will be interesting to see my email is mariana.soffer@coinfabrik.com

Comment: You might not want to leave your contact information on a public page like this

Comment: @marianasoffer, I replied to your email , in spanish.

Comment: why do you say so henk?

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions, but I recommend coinmeterics and Google's bigquery dataset for ethereum.

You can access internal transactions, traces, contracts etc.

For example, heres a chart that aggregates ethereum transfers and costs.
[image]
Apart from this, heres the daily transfers, senders and receivers for OmiseGo, a popular ERC20 token
[image]

[Coinmetrics](https://coinmetrics.io/data-downloads/)
[Ethereum BigQuery Dataset](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/ethereum-bigquery-public-dataset-smart-contract-analytics)